# How do i stop core files from dumping into core directory on MAC

Tags: sudo, cpu-cores

Core files are taking over my core folder. My system has been as high as 932GB.  I have to continually go in multiple times a day to delete them manually.

Imac running Mac0s Mojave 10.14. Last week core files totaling 800gb. System file came back to 45gb.  Same thing happening now.  Rang Apple. Reset the SMC - no change. Reset the NVRAM - no change. Reinstall the OS software - no change. Sent to next level support - tech guy says that the core files are related to a 3rd party application and I need to delete all.  I can delete them by going into terminal and running `sudo rm -f/cores/core.*` but this is a pain so looking for a method of stopping them from going into the folder at all. Any suggestions

Comment: You might try linking the directory to `/dev/null`. I do not know if the system will tolerate that or override it, but even so, it is just a temporary kludge. Likely some third-party software is crashing or corrupting your system, and you ought to identify it and remove it (preferably reinstall from scratch without it).

Comment: yes I have started to delete 3rd parties but I might restore to a backup from about a month ago first - I am not technical so just feeling my way through this